# Bringing to the UK the daughter of a British Citizen

Tags: visa

I lived in UK in between 1997 to 2009 on work permit initially then later in 2003 i received British Passport. My wife got Indefinite stay in 2002, but she never applied for passport or naturalization. We left to India in 2009 under very difficult circumstances to save my wife life from the negligence of NHS trust. My daughter was born in India in 2001 (we were Indian citizens) and she obtained Indefinite stay in 2005/2006,however she never visited UK. My son was born in 2006 in UK and he received British passport. So me and my son are British, but not my wife and daughter

I have returned to UK in Oct 2016 to find employment in IT sector.

Since the ILR expires if the person continuously lives in outside of UK, 
1. what would be the best option to get my daughter to UK to study her A-levels? 2. Shall i able to renew her previous ILR some how? 
3. or should i use the option of 'spouse or family of settled person' to get fresh visa?
4. What would be the minimum income i need to show to the home office?
5. or is getting her to EU first and then to UK?

Comment: Have you checked whether your daughter is a British citizen by descent?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan the daughter was born two years before Satish became a British citizen and she has never visited the UK. How would she have British citizenship by descent?

Comment: @phoog Good point. I was confused about the chronology.